# How can I make my square image responsive?

Tags: html, css, responsive-images

I need to create a responsive square image, and I've followed different answers from here but something is going on.  I can see my square DIV (because it has a black background), but the image that goes in it is not in the square, it's like it's offset for some reason and I can't figure out why.

It's best to see my entire code in [Codepen](https://codepen.io/paulamourad/pen/gOLmebM).

```css
/* Cards */

.card-main-container {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.card-wrapper {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.card-img-square {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  width: 30%;
  padding-bottom: 30%;
  margin: 1.66%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.card-img-square img {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: absolute;
}

.card-information-container {
  background-color: $white;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  padding-top: 6px;
}

.card-region-commune {
  line-height: 1.4em;
  color: $disclaimer;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
  min-height: 34px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.card-category {
  font-size: 0.8em;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: $placeholder;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.card-title {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  color: $secondary-color;
}

.card-description {
  color: $secondary-color;
  font-size: 0.9em;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.card-category,
.card-title {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.card-description {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
  min-height: 42px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="col card-wrapper">
  <div class="col-12">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col card-information-container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col card-img-square">
            <img src="https://insideretail.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/hairdresser.jpg" class="img-fluid" />
          </div>
          <div class="col text-left">
            <img src="images/service-stars-demo.svg" alt="Ranking">
            <!-- Insignia Verificado -->
            <p class="card-item-indication"><i class="fas fa-shield-check pr-1"></i> Text</p>


          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
      <!-- /Card 1-->
```

Comment: `height: 90%;
  /* = 100% - 2*5% padding */
  width: 90%;
  /* = 100% - 2*5% padding */`  **does not make a square** if your wrapper is not a square. since , you did set text-align:center earlier, your absolute image stands on *(drawn from)* the middle and is actually overflowing on the right . possible average  update https://jsfiddle.net/3hcrb1do/1/

Answer (score 0):

I wrapped the `img` tag with a new `div` has your class to avoid change the *.col* width and make the `img` has full width with your recommended padding, and it's looking good on different screens. You can check the changes from here https://codepen.io/abdelrhman-m27/pen/jOVBzLx